# How is a batch file (`.cmd` / `.bat`) file executed on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, kernel, win32

### Context

On Windows, the application responsible for opening a given file type (identified by its extension) is resolved using file associations defined (among a few other places) in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Usually, if I wanted to make a file with a given extension executable, I'd set its file association to the preferred interpreter program. For example, if I wanted to make `.ps1` files execute in PowerShell just by invoking them, I'd add `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ps1` pointing to some file type and then in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<filetype>\shell\open\command`, write the interpreter and arguments to use (e.g. `powershell.exe "%1"`).

### Question

I always assumed that batch files (`.cmd`/`.bat`) are associated the same way. However, upon checking `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\open\command`, the value is `"%1" %*`, which is the same as for `.exe` files. This suggests that execution of batch files is handled through another mechanism.

However, unlike with `.exe`, you cannot pass a batch file path to `CreateProcess` directly. According to a ProcMon trace of a file manager invoking a batch file, the `CreateProcess` call already invokes `cmd.exe` with the batch file as an argument.

This would lead me to believe that execution of batch files is handled somewhere inside the Win32 library code. Is that correct?

Bonus question: Why are batch files not handled using standard file associations, like `.vbs` and other script files that are supported by default?

---

Random observation: only the following file extensions are handled by calling `"%1" %*`: `.exe`, `.com`, `.bat`/`.cmd`, `.pif` (at least on my computer)

Comment: so my take (going back to win3) is that its just a feature of the shell. fileopen is no different in outcome from pasting the path to a file into the run bar, or executing a command from it for that matter. in terms of the code executing the batch, it's in cmd.exe.  in old windows, the gui shell relied on an underlying command.com shell, so this kind of thing just happened naturally, and as it grew up, MS preserved some of the integration with the command shell as features. Also, in the old days file type extensions were mostly for installed software, not integrated parts of the shell